# How to properly delegate interface to sister class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, virtual-functions

Let's assume I have classes `Child` and `Parent`, where `Child` extends the `Parent`:

```
class Parent {
    void foo() {cout << "foo\n";}
    void bar() {cout << "bar\n";}
    void jar() {cout << "jar\n";}
};

class Child: public Parent {
    void child_method1();
    void child_method2();
};
```

Now I want to export some of the `Child` functionality using the following interface:

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual ~Interface(){}

    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;

protected:
    Interface(){}
};
```

As you can see the interface methods are all already implemented in `Parent`. How do I properly define `Child` so that the `Interface` is delegated to the `Parent` ?

I'm trying to do it like:

```
class Child: public Parent, public Interface {
    void child_method1();
    void child_method2();
}
```

But the compiler complains that the virtual methods `foo()` and `bar()` are not implemented in `Child`.

If I write an explicit delegation like this:

```
class Child: public Parent, public Interface {
    void foo() {Parent::foo();}
    void bar() {Parent::bar();}

    void child_method1();
    void child_method2();
}
```

the compiler doesn't complain.
Is it necessary to write the explicit delegation? What is the proper way to delegate the virtual methods to a sister class?

Comment: It looks like your inheritance tree is messed up. If you have no need to override methods in derived class then there is no point in having virtual functions. There is no point for this `Interface` to exist, just pass a reference to `Parent` instead.

Comment: Yes, you need to spell it out explicitly. The classes are unrelated in your example. `Parent::foo` doesn't automatically become the implementation of `Interface::foo`. But I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Take a step back. Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary to write the explicit delegation?

Yes, otherwise you will receive a compilation error.

> What is the proper way?

To stop right there and re-consider your design.

Why marking the functions as `virtual`, when there is no need of overriding these functions in the derived class?

You could just pass a reference to the parent class, instead of using the interface, which seems useless now.